# Display data out of a list in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display the items out of my class in div-containers.

my code looks like this:

```
List<Produkte> PListe = Produkte.Anzeige(wert);
div class="row">
{
foreach (var item in PListe)
{ 
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <figure class="figure">

  <img src="~/pictures/@(item.name).jpg" alt="@item.name">
  <figcaption class="figure-caption"> @item.name </figcaption> 

  </figure>
  </div>

}
</div>
}
```

it should be two rows with each 4 items. but the problem is in the second row the div-container shift and get displayed wrong: 
 after the first picture in the second row is a big gap (empty divs?!) and then it goes on with the other pictures.

can you help me to solve this?

im a total beginner in this so please lots of explaining

Comment: What's the actual HTML generated by this code?  Is it what you expected it to be?  Is this actually a CSS styling problem instead?

Comment: @David what do you mean with "actual HTML"? no i expected it to be 2 rows with each 4 items. so item,item,item,item (new line) item,item,item,item. but its: item,item,item,item (new line) blank, blank, blank, item (new line) item,item,item, blank.

Comment: You're showing (broken) server-side code which generates HTML to be sent to the browser.  What is that resulting HTML in the browser?  Not a description of what the rendering of it looks like, but what is the *actual HTML* that the browser is using to render the page?  How does it compare to the HTML that you expected this code to generate?

Comment: @David: It's quite easy to picture the generated HTML here, and more readable than the actual stuff. And what do you think is 'broken' ?

Comment: @usernumber - you are trying to use a responsive-UI feature to create a wrap panel. That's not what it's for. Consider rewriting the loop to two loops generating a `<div row>` for each batch.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: It is easy to make assumptions about the output HTML, yes. But if the OP is claiming that the generated HTML is incorrect in some way, then a good debugging step would be for the OP to actually examine that generated HTML and compare it to what was expected. Perhaps his expectations were incorrect. That's worth validating. As for why it's "broken", there's that broken `<div>` tag for starters, plus the variable declaration which doesn't really belong in a view, and won't work without the Razor `@` prefix, and the missing `@` opening the `foreach`.  Plus the random `{` and `}`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman so you mean i would have to code something like <div class="row"> foreach{]</div> <div class=row> foreach{] </div> ? ive also tried to put in the foreach-loop and i tried to put around it a for-loop but both tries failed